# Output UiPath - Get Mail: Code: generalException Message: An error occurred sending the request

Tags: office365, ms-office, rpa, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I'm facing some problems in the Office 365 "get mail" activity. I inform you, it was working before, but now it's having problems. And the same code is running no problem on my friend's pc.

---

**Output**

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DokO.png)

---

**Test bench**

[Test bench - Get Mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ivr.png)

[Properties microsoft office 365 scope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OenXA.png)

[Properties get mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2hpw.png)

---

**Local**

$exceptionDetails RemoteException wrapping Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalExceptionMessage: An error occurred sending the request.  ---> RemoteException wrapping Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Error: ClientId is not a GUID.
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractApplicationBuilder`1.Validate()   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Validate()   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.AbstractApplicationBuilder`1.BuildConfiguration()   at UiPath.Shared.Authentication.Microsoft.Services.MsalLogonService.GetPublicApplication(OAuthDataOptions oauth)   at UiPath.Shared.Authentication.Microsoft.Services.MsalLogonService.GetClientApplication(OAuthDataOptions oauth)   at UiPath.Shared.Authentication.Microsoft.Services.MsalLogonService.d__10.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.GraphClientServiceFactory.d__16.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.GraphClientServiceFactory.d__14.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.GraphClientServiceFactory.d__25.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.GraphClientServiceFactory.d__13.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Authentication.Microsoft.Extensions.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.d__4.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandler.d__16.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Graph.SimpleHttpProvider.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.Graph.SimpleHttpProvider.d__13.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Graph.SimpleHttpProvider.d__10.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__40.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__34`1.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at Microsoft.Graph.UserMailFoldersCollectionRequest.d__3.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.Mail.Extensions.GraphServiceClientExtensions.d__33.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.Mail.Extensions.GraphServiceClientExtensions.d__31.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.Shared.Services.Graph.Mail.Extensions.GraphServiceClientExtensions.d__10.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)   at UiPath.MicrosoftOffice365.Services.GraphServiceClientProxy.d__70.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   at UiPath.MicrosoftOffice365.Activities.Mail.GetMail.d__42.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at UiPath.Shared.Activities.AsyncTaskCodeActivityImplementation.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)   at UiPath.Shared.Activities.AsyncTaskCodeActivity.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)   at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

I changed the InteractiveToken **Authentication Type** to UsernameAndPassword. And the same error occurred.